# What are good methods for debugging a silently broken template tag?

Tags: django, templates, markdown, templatetags

I have a template that calls the markdown template tag from the django.contrib.markup library. On my local system it works fine, but on the server, for some reason, the content|markdown call returns just the content, not marked up. No error is thrown in any of the logs, and TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True doesn't get me anything. I've put calls in the actual markdown() function, and they never get called. So my best guess is that for some reason the load markup call at the top of the template is failing.

Are there good ways to emulate the template environment and find out what's happening? Debugging tools? Things to look for?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, doesn't the markdown filter require a module be loaded and accessible on the default path or whatnot? Is that also available on the (remote?) server? Can you run the django shell on the server and "import markdown" or whatever the module name is?

Comment: import markdown works in the django shell. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270893/cannot-import-markdown-because-of-command-line-logging-level is the other half of this bug, figured out afterward and more specific, less useful later.

Answer (score 0):

You could put something in the template tag module that records when the module is loaded, so you could at least confirm whether or not the markdown filter is being loaded in at all.

You could also create another function in the same template file called "tester" or something that simply appends and prepends the word "TEST" to the string...then just see if any of the filters in that module are running correctly.

Comment: Do you know approximately where to look in the template code in Django? I'm finding it confusing to find where the tags get loaded.

Comment: You already said you put calls in the markdown function. Just put some right at the top; they will get run when the module is loaded in the very first time.