# Cannot import markdown because of COMMAND_LINE_LOGGING_LEVEL

Tags: python, django, markdown

I've got a weird error where I can import markdown in Python, and I can import markdown in python inside the Django runserver, but I get the following when trying to import markdown inside of gunicorn's app server.

*** ImportError: cannot import name COMMAND_LINE_LOGGING_LEVEL

This is even more confusing because I found the only place where COMMAND_LINE_LOGGING_LEVEL is referenced in markdown (or any of the code I'm using) -- one line, defining it, in the markdown **init**.py, and I commented it out. I still get this error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gunicorn, for reasons I don't understand yet, adds the virtualenv/bin directory to the sys.path. Markdown installs a markdown.py into that bin directory. That markdown.py tries to import COMMAND_LINE_LOGGING_LEVEL from markdown the library. This results in a circular failure.

I don't know why Gunicorn does this, and probably it shouldn't. My convenience fix is to add the following to the server's local_settings.py

```
import sys
for i, path in enumerate(sys.path):
    if path.endswith('bin'):
        del sys.path[i]
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this error by removing the .py extension from markdown.py in whatever/bin. This apparently prevented it from importing itself instead of the markdown module in site-packages.

Comment: This is probably the wrong answer for several reasons. 1: Any reinstall of markdown will cause markdown.py to reappear, causing bugs down the road. 2: Really bad is the situation I have (becoming more common) with automated system setup, although you could also automate the deletion of the file. 3: markdown.py provides a useful function, in that it's the command line interface to markdown, and so removing it may remove functionality for some users or down the road.

Comment: Good points all, but I encountered this error outside any kind of gunicorn/django environment. Python always looks first in the current directory for imports (therefore "import foo" in a file named "foo.py" will import itself instead of the library named "foo" which you intended.) In my case there's no other way to fix this but modifying "bin/markdown.py".

Comment: I actually think this is a bug in markdown. markdown.py has a pre-import routine modifying the sys.path, just like the one you wrote above, but only executes on windows. It would be better to do it always. I'll try contacting the developer.